# The vertical scrollbar isnt working when necessary

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller

Whenever I add too much items to the page and those use a space higher than the screen offers it'd activate the scroll bar (the vertical one), but it just doesnt. probably it's just some CSS configuration I guess. but I'm really stuck with this one.

When that happens you cant access the content of the page that is under the screen field, even tho it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code on CSS

```
body, html { 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```